# Cut/delete a portion of an image (JPG)

Tags: c#, image, crop, editing

Is there any way to programatically delete a the portion of JPG image (rectangular) from the JPG image. By some trial and error I can adjust the XY cordinates to adjust to my requirement (to cut the username box)

All the questions seem to need the cropped rectangular portion whereas I neeed the original image with rectangular potion blank-ed out.

Comment: You can check the condition if username or password is wrong make the other textbox visiblity false and then take screenshot.

Comment: coder: Its more about image editing in c# rather than web programming. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 1):

This sample code takes the lower-right quadrant of an image. It should be enough for you to work with and get an idea::

```
string path = "C:\\test.jpg";
using (Bitmap orignal = new Bitmap(path))
{
        using (Bitmap newimage = new Bitmap((int)(orignal.Width * 0.5), (int)(orignal.Height * 0.5)))
        {
                using (Graphics newgraphics = Graphics.FromImage(newimage))
                {
                        newgraphics.DrawImage(orignal, 0, 0, new Rectangle(newimage.Width, newimage.Height, orignal.Width - newimage.Width, orignal.Height - newimage.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        newgraphics.Flush();
                }


                newimage.Save(new System.IO.FileInfo(path).DirectoryName + "out.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
}
```

Comment: The solution you gave was to create a new image that was cropped from the original one. What I need is to remove a certain portion of Image or in other words, create a new image similar to the original but with certain portion blanked out.